# Infinite Loop for cleaning

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking to loop this to clean out ~1000000 emails any help appreciated!

```
function batchDeleteA() {
var batchSize = 100 // Process up to 100 threads at once
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox older_than:2d');
for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation of your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm trying to Loop the function automatically because, it only can delete up to 100 emails at a time. However, I have 1,058,028 and I'm not sure how to loop it as I am not well versed in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, when you check `threads.length`, it's 1,058,028. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a large loop, you probably want to use a queue system where you use timeouts to do the loop. Basic idea below with hard coded array.

```js
function batchDeleteA() {
  //var batchSize = 100;
  var batchSize = 3;

  // var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox older_than:2d');
  var threads = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  var removeBatch = function() {
    var batch = threads.splice(0, Math.min(batchSize, threads.length));
    // GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(batch);

    if (threads.length) {
      console.log("remaining: ", threads.length);
      window.setTimeout(removeBatch, 1);
    } else {
      console.log("complete");
    }
  };

  removeBatch();

}

batchDeleteA()
```

If you are getting throttled, you can increase the timeout from 1 to a larger number of milliseconds.